# conditional compilation for test / deploy build with raspberry pi

Tags: build, clojure, leiningen, conditional-compilation

I am building an application for the raspberry pi and use pi4j as a dependency for Software PWM on GPIO. I'd like to test my code on my local machine though, so I would like to compile my code without the pi4j dependency and skip method calls to the library.

Example code:

```
(ns led-server.model
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log])
  (:import [com.pi4j.wiringpi SoftPwm Gpio])) ;; pi4j dependency, only compiles on rPi


(defn- soft-pwm-write [pin value]
  (let [ival (Math/round (double (* value RANGE)))]
    (SoftPwm/softPwmWrite pin ival) ;; call to pi4j. This is what I want to skip
    (log/info "pin" pin "set to" ival))
  )
```

pi4j requires the wiringPi C library, which is only available on the raspberry pi (which makes sense). For testing on my dev machine it would be sufficient to see the log printout. I don't want to comment out the `:import` and method calls for testing, I would like a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the question if conditional compilation is the best approach here, it is not difficult to compile *files* conditionally with leiningen: put the files you want to compile conditionally in a folder different than src/clj, and define it as a source folder in a profile:

```
:profiles {
    :native {:source-paths ["src/native/clj/"]}
    :mock {:source-paths ["src/mock/clj/"]}
```

Then, run leininig with profile:

```
lein with-profiles +mock repl
```

See more at https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md

In your situation, you could define a protocol, provide 2 implementations and make sure you load only the classes relevant to your environment.

Comment: Ok neat, this looks like it can work. You mentioned that conditional compilation might not be the right way to tackle this; what would you suggest instead?

Comment: You could decide at run-time whether to load the Pi class and, if desired, do something like (-> "com.pi4j.wiringpi.SoftPwm"  Class/forName (.getMethod "softPwmWrite" arg-types) (.invoke nil pin vals)). If you don't execute this code the Pi class will not be loaded. Don't :import.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll see what fits better, second option does not seem cleaner though.